# How to add and delete items in an XML node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partner id="A12345">
   <classes>
      <class id="101"
            <documents>
                <document isWaived="true" name="Doc 1">true</document>
                <document isWaived="false" name="Doc 2">false</document>
            </documents>
        </class>
    </classes>
</partner>
```

In the above xml, I have to delete all items in documents node first, so that I have to get the following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partner id="A12345">
   <classes>
      <class id="101"
            <documents>
            </documents>
        </class>
    </classes>
</partner>
```

And wanted to add a new set of documents to get the following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partner id="A12345">
   <classes>
      <class id="101"
            <documents>
                <document isWaived="false" name="Doc 3">false</document>
            </documents>
        </class>
    </classes>
</partner>
```

I currently uses the following xsl to delete the contents in document node.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="document" />
```

But this gives an output like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partner id="A12345">
   <classes>
      <class id="101"
            <documents/>
        </class>
    </classes>
</partner>
```

Now, I have to add some items to a node array. How can we do this.
Can anybody help on deleting the contents of a node and adding a new value.

Comment: Where will the new `document` nodes come from? Do you just want to hard-code them in the XSLT?

Comment: Are those static items you want to add or do you want to generate them somehow? If they are static you could simply change your documents template and insert new items in there with <xsl:copy><xsl:element name="XYZ">example</xsl:element></xsl:copy>

Comment: New Document, (Doc 3 in example) will be static.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your output to be static I would just change the documents template like:

```
<xsl:template match="documents">
    <xsl:copy>
        <document isWaived="false" name="Doc 3">false</document>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Cosidered your comment you are searching for the tokenize() function.

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($documentstring,';')"> <!-- the second argument is the character you want to split the string on -->
     <document isWaived="false" name="{.}"> 
         <!-- The braces allow you to run codesegments inside the attribute -->
     </document>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked.
And how if I have an array of Documents to be added.
Consider I have a String array with Document names, and wanted to create <document/> corresponding to each item in array.